# Comparison: motorcycle paddock stand vs lift vs table lift?

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance

what are advantanges and disadvantages of paddock stand , lift and table lift regards to motorcycle maintenance work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paddock stand**: fast, easy, cheap, totally portable, and doesn't require much storage space. Holds the bike upright in a very stable condition so you can easily work on it. Requires the front* and rear suspension to be intact to use. Have to bend over and crawl on the floor.

* The front tire and forks must be installed unless you have a front stand (of which there are at least two variants, one that goes under the forks and one goes under the triple tree).

**Motorcycle lift**: I presume you mean a lift that goes under the or attaches to engine to support the bike. Much more expensive than the paddock stand, somewhat portable, requires some storage space (generally on the floor because of bulk and weight), and slightly more difficult to use. Holds the bike upright and very stable, but the bike usually shouldn't be mounted by a rider. Great for doing work that requires removing front and rear suspension on a bike with no center stand. Lifts the bike up higher than a paddock stand.

**Table lift**: Very easy to work on the bike as the component being worked on can always be at chest level. Note that the table lift should be used in conjunction with other lifts, as the table lift is really for increasing the height of the horizontal surface the bike is on. A popular method is to use wheel chocks and tie-downs for securing the bike while on the lift, though this is impractical when working on front suspension or wheel components. This generally requires dedicated floor space, is portable only in the sense that everything can be moved, and is more expensive than all other options, especially considering that other options are required to make full use.

There are still many other stands that can be used to accomplish different or even the same goals.

Answer (score 0):

Motorcycle maintenance depends on your motorcycle. And depends on the maintenance job you intend to do. Do you really need a table life for lubing the chain or perhaps changing the Tyre ? How much money are you planning  to spend on the lift/paddock/table-lift? Do you know how to fix the engine should there be anything wrong? Then a lift table is a lot more convenient. What is cheaper, the mechanic or the table-lift? And usually a person who know the job knows the tools to use.
Or else in simple words, maintaining a motorcycle can be done by lubing the chain and changing the oil at the rite time. these are the very basics and a paddock should help you get through these tasks. And this may not be the answer you were looking for. The bigger tasks like changing the break-pads, changing the sprockets, changing the coolants (if its a liquid cooled), cleaning the carb and filter require a little more skills and experience.